# How to find out which custom listeners are attached to a trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm struggling trying to find the place in code which reacts on the trigger:

```
var $comboBox = $(fieldSelector);
var kComboBox = $comboBox.data(fieldType);
kComboBox.trigger("change");
```

I found that `kComboBox.trigger("change")` affects my combobox by clearing the text inside it and now I'm trying to find what code does that.

I was trying to find attached methods like `.bind("change")`, `.on("change")`  or `.change`, but I can't find a suitable one.

Is there any method to get the list of listeners for this trigger or find it manually is the only way to get them?

Comment: You can check the events bound to an element (and its parents) using devtools. Inspect the element, then click 'event listeners'

Comment: maybe just use  debuger, dev tools. or get event callbacks jQuery._data( elem, "events" ); and wrap callbacks in higer order loging function